# Работа с миграциями в Laravel

Tags: php, база-данных, laravel, миграция

Такие вопросы по миграциям в Laravel:

1. Допустим, у меня есть 1 миграция (создание таблицы) - **уже сделанная**, то есть была набрана команда `php artisan migrate`, a 
   затем я делаю другие изменения (например, изменение структуры другой таблицы), а потом набираю команду `php artisan migrate` - обработаются все миграции, включая уже обработанную ранее первую, или Laravel использует в данной ситуации контроль версий (о котором пишется в документации) и обработает только последнюю (новую)?
2. В контексте первого вопроса, будет лучше делать для каждого действия/для 
   действия с одной и той же таблицей отдельную миграцию или же редактировать 
   ту же самую миграцию, увеличивая batch count?
3. Метод `down()`. Правильно ли я понимаю, что если ты в методе `run()`
   создал, например, 2 таблицы, добавил колонку в 3-ей и изменил тип
   данных для колонки в 4-ой, то в методе `down()` надо вручную в
   точности сделать всё наоборот, возвращая к состоянию до метода
   `run()`?

Comment: _обработаются все миграции?_ - да. Возможно к команде `php artisan migrate` можно дописывать параметры для выполнения конкретной миграции, но это только мои предположения.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

1. Тут 2 варианта:

   - Eсли вы разрабатываете, здесь и сейчас, с нуля и поняли, что блин, а вот тут не хватает чего-то,- вы можете сделать `php artisan migrate:refresh` т.е. сбросить и создать все таблицы
   - У вас команда или проект который уже в работе, и вам нужно добавить, что-то новое, тогда вы должны создать миграцию с двумя методами `up` и `down`, причем `down` будет отменять все то что добавили в `up`
2. Этот вопрос закрывается в первом пункте, смотря, что и для чего вам надо.
3. Лучше конечно что б в одной миграции в 3 таблицы не создавали и каждая миграция имела свое название: например `create_statuses_table`, `add_field_status_to_orders_table`, соответственно если вы что-то добавили в `up` то в `down` это следует отменять.

Например:

```
/**
 * Run the migrations.
 *
 * @return void
 */
public function up()
{
    Schema::table('shops', function (Blueprint $table) {
        $table->json('suppliers_settings')->nullable()->after('suppliers');
    });
}

/**
 * Reverse the migrations.
 *
 * @return void
 */
public function down()
{
    Schema::table('shops', function (Blueprint $table) {
        $table->dropColumn('suppliers_settings');
    });
}
```

Так же хорошо делать команду `php artisan migrate --step`, что бы каждой миграции давался свой номер и потом можно было бы отменять по одной миграции назад при помощи команды `php atisan migrate:rollback`

Так же перед тем как выкатить на сервер изменение было бы не плохо проверять что у вас обе команды работают верно `up()` и `down()`, т.е. запустите разок `php artisan migrate --step` и `php atisan migrate:rollback`, что б удостовериться, что все идет без ошибок!

Comment: в целом понятно, спасибо за пояснения!